# Cyclic voltammetry for irreversible reactions

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

I'm new to electrochemistry and I was wondering two things, sorry if these two problems are trivial but I just can't find anything close to this in the literature.

First, the following reaction is irreversible, right? an intermediate Q is formed:
$B + e^{-} \rightarrow Q$

and another reaction follows where it is converted to a different product X:

$Q \rightarrow X$.

Then I'm supposed to sketch a cyclic voltammogram (CV) of this process, but I was taught that for irreversible processes a CV is not useful.

I looked pretty much all day for a similar reaction and the closest I could find is in "A Practical Beginner’s Guide to Cyclic Voltammetry" where the following reactions are presented:

$\text{Ox} + e^{-} \rightleftharpoons \text{Red}$

$\text{Red} \rightarrow Z$

These are defined as EC coupled reaction: reversible electron transfer Er following by an irreversible homogeneous chemical reaction Ci.

The ones I am given are not the same, I think. But I have no idea how to sketch a CV for that process. Am I interpreting the given reactions wrongly?

[image]

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_voltammetry. In the cathodic scan, the scan voltage goes from more positive  to less positive w.r.t. the reference potential. Then you get a reduction of B to Q. Then Q irreversibly goes to X, which is not electroactive. So the reverse scan shows no oxidation peak current because Q is gone and X is not electroactive, i.e., it cannot be significantly oxidized in the CV situation.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. What you describe seems like an irreversible process, which should look something like this, I think (see figure in question, don't know how to add it here).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Alright. I'm glad I asked this, otherwise I would have assumed that the first reaction was irreversible. So it is an entirely irreversible reaction then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I found a similar explanation in this source (see below). At slower scan rates the cyclic voltammogram would look similar to what I posted in my question. Thanks for the clarification!
<https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Analytical_Sciences_Digital_Library/JASDL/Courseware/Analytical_Electrochemistry%3A_The_Basic_Concepts/04_Voltammetric_Methods/A._Basics_of_Voltammetry/02_Potential_Sweep_Methods/b)_Cyclic_Voltammetry/iii)_Chemical__reactions__coupled__to__electron__transfer>

Comment: Corrected version of previous comment: Just to be clear: the first scenario has two irreversible steps, while the second has a reversible redox followed by Red going irreversibly to Z. If that last step is slow relative to the reversible redox, then you would get anodic peaks. But repeated cycling would show all peaks gradually getting smaller as Z accumulates and does nothing in the CV situation.